# Average of X*Y items and keeping dimensions of the numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

How do you take an average of for example four nearby items (2*2) on two dimensional array? My input is:

```
[[1,1,1,1],
 [1,1,0,0],
 [0,0,1,1],
 [0,0,0,0]]
```

Which should result:

```
[[1, 0.5],
 [0, 0.5]]
```

numpy.mean(x.reshape(-1, 4), 1) will flatten array and average four items slightly in wrong order.

**Additional info**

Array is produced for example by this method:

```
n = 10
l = 100
A = np.zeros((l, l))
points = l*np.random.random((2, n**2))
A[(points[0]).astype(np.int), (points[1]).astype(np.int)] = 1
A = ndimage.gaussian_filter(A, sigma=l/(4.*n))
```

Comment: How does that output work? Do you mean to evaluate the `mean` of smaller individual `2 x 2` blocks of your array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way with reshaping and summing -

```
m,n = A.shape
A.reshape(m/2,2,n/2,2).sum(axis=(1,3))/4.0
```

Of course, it assumes that the number of rows and columns are divisible by `2`.

Sample run -

```
In [87]: A
Out[87]: 
array([[8, 4, 6, 8, 1, 1],
       [6, 7, 8, 5, 3, 4],
       [1, 8, 8, 4, 7, 6],
       [1, 8, 7, 7, 2, 4]])

In [88]: m,n = A.shape

In [89]: A.reshape(m/2,2,n/2,2).sum(axis=(1,3))/4.0
Out[89]: 
array([[ 6.25,  6.75,  2.25],
       [ 4.5 ,  6.5 ,  4.75]])
```

Comment: One of these days I should *really* get myself to understand this approach:)

Comment: Some part of the code gave warning on jupyter: DeprecationWarning: using a non-integer number instead of an integer will result in an error in the future app.launch_new_instance(). Maybe there is something on my original array... but this seems to work.

Comment: @MarkokraM See if this avoids the error : `np.true_divide(A.reshape(m/2,2,n/2,2).sum(axis=(1,3)),4)`? Basically that division factor needs to be a float. So, it has to be something like `float(X*Y)`. Or, as suggested earlier in the comment, use `np.true_divide()`. I am guessing the warning is because of it.

Comment: @MarkokraM The warning says "using a non-integer number instead of an integer". Could it be that `m/2` or `n/2` is non-integer? That is, are your dimensions even?

Comment: @AndrasDeak I think in that case, it would throw an error instead of warning.

Comment: @Divakar sorry, you're right, even the number of elements wouldn't add up. Then the warning message is worded in a weird way...since you're doing the opposite: using integer numbers instead of non-integers (I would think).

Comment: I added new info to the question for DeprecationWarning.

Comment: @MarkokraM I am not getting any warning when running the code with the added sample data. Also, did you try `np.true_divide()` and see if the warning still persists?

Comment: Yes, I tried, but it gives another error: invalid number of arguments. Anaconda3-2.4.1-MacOSX-x86_64

Comment: @MarkokraM Of course not just `np.true_divide()`! I meant `np.true_divide(A.reshape(m/2,2,n/2,2).sum(axis=(1,3)),4)`.

Comment: Fairly certain that the warning is for floats passed to `reshape`; you could use `A.reshape(m//2,2,n//2,2)` instead (assuming `m` and `n` are even of course). Also, you could use `mean` instead of summing and dividing, e.g. `A.reshape(m//2,2,n//2,2).mean(axis=(1,3))`!

Comment: @ajcr Ah yes! That might be it, I am on Python 2.7 and that's why it didn't show that warning I guess. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could also use a 2D filter:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import ndimage

A=np.array([[1,1,1,1],
 [1,1,0,0],
 [0,0,1,1],
 [0,0,0,0]],dtype=float)

k=np.array([[1,1],[1,1]])/4.
B=ndimage.convolve(A, k, mode='constant', cval=0.0)
C=B[0:-1:2,0:-1:2]
```

B contains the spatial average, where the 2x2 window is moved in steps of 1. If you only want the spatial average over disjunct 2x2 regions, appropriate indexing, as in C, will provide that.